# converting minutes to seconds and trying to keep counting up or down every second

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm converting time(value comes in minutes) to seconds using MomentJS + Moment Duration Format and then I'm trying to keep counting up or down every second like a timer.

I've made an example below which is able to convert the time from minutes to seconds and display the timer in minutes however, I'm not able to make it count

I'm not sure if MomentJS is able to do this with the extra plugin([Moment Duration Format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)).

Any ideas?

```js
var tar = $('span');

test(tar, 3)

function test(tar, time) {
  setInterval(function() {
    var minsToSecs = moment.duration(time, 'minutes').asSeconds(),
      timeInSeconds = minsToSecs++,
      formattedDur = moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00").add(timeInSeconds, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss");

    tar.html(formattedDur);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Try `timeInSeconds = minsToSecs + 1`. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) for details

Comment: I tried this however, it's not working for me. It gives 00:03:01 but it doesn't keep counting. Perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: Oh, I see. You're starting each iteration at the same point, ie `"1900-01-01 00:00:00"`. You should store that value externally to the interval callback and update it with each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.

```js
var tar = $('span');
var instant = moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00");

test(tar, 3)

function test(tar, time) {
    var minsToSecs = moment.duration(time, 'minutes').asSeconds(),
      timeInSeconds = minsToSecs;

  setInterval(function() {
      formattedDur = instant.add(timeInSeconds, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss");
      timeInSeconds= 1;

    tar.html(formattedDur);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Comment: If anybody also wants to know how to count down, timeInSeconds = -1

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comments above...

```js
var tar = $('span');
var instant = moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00");

test(tar, 3)

function test(tar, time) {
    var minsToSecs = moment.duration(time, 'minutes').asSeconds(),
      timeInSeconds = minsToSecs;

  setInterval(function() {
      formattedDur = instant.add(timeInSeconds, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss");
      timeInSeconds= 1;

    tar.html(formattedDur);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Comment: This is counting the seconds however, it's also increasing the minutes by 3 seconds each second

Comment: I edited it to run correctly, it should appear whenever it is peer edited.

Comment: @user1563074 Can  you post a new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration, you're converting 3 minutes to seconds, then assigning to to time in seconds. Then you add one to minsToSeconds which at this point is not used anymore. TimeInSeconds is then added to your template. Because time never changes, which all these other values are based on, your time never changes. Find a way to increment 'time' instead and that will make your clock go.